# Extra space in height, android xml layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, xml-layout

i am having a linear layout for which i am using wrap content with height. But i am getting some extra space after all the elements even after giving wrap content. However, if i manually supply the height to "220dp", then its properly formatted. I want to use wrap content and solve this problem. Please provide your valuable suggestions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/layout3" android:background="@drawable/question_backgrund"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/question_number1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:text="1" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/answer_icon1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="220dp" android:contentDescription="Answer status"
            android:src="@drawable/answer_status" android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/comment_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/write_comments_icon" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/comment_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="title" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/write_comments"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp" android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:ems="10" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/submit" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop = "10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/done"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is there a `android:layout_weight="1"` on the main layout ?
How much space is there ? Some element have natural padding, if you have only <8 dp it may come from that.
It may also comes from the background image of the main layout, is it a 9patch image ? Do you correctly yell the content to take the complete space of the image ?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, it was coming from the background image!